# trying to add dictionary objects to an NSMutableArray - afterward array returns null?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I just did a search for my particular question and although the answers are close, I can't get my head around the answer...so I need some assistance.

I'd like to populate an array (NSMutableArray I suppose) with a group of dictionary objects that are parsed from JSON strings...the dictionary part I got, the JSON parsing I got, but when I try to put these objects into the NSMutableArray and NSLog it I get (null)... here are my steps (in a general way)

**edit 1:**
-The array I am creating is called NewFinalArray. it is an NSMutableArray, declared at the .h file and synthesized (and now alloc'd and init'd) as noted in the viewDidLoad method of the DetailViewController. It's contents are to be displayed in a  UITableView.

-In DetailViewController, I have been successful in creating a plain NSArray/NSMutableArray and populating it with values that display in my UITableView.

-In the new scenario, I am receiving the information to be displayed through JSON strings which are retrievable through dictionary objects. I am using the Stig JSON libraries for iPHone/iPad. I have no problems there.

-All I wanted to do is getting the existing dictionary objects (which I can loop through from the existing array and see) and add them to a new Array to be used for displaying menu items in my UITableview.

1. I declared my mutableArray in my .h file

   ```
   @interface blah : ...,...,...{
   NSMutableArray *newFinalArray;
    // other vars and IBOutlets
   }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *newFinalArray;

    // other @property and (IBAction) stuff
    @end
   ```
2. I then synthesize it in my .m file... I even alloc/inited it at viewDidLoad (it's a DetailViewController)

   ```
    @synthesize this,that, newFinalArray; // keep track of newFinalArray, that's the one I want

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
      // other code
      [[newFinalArray alloc] init]; // ya returns a warning, about not responding to alloc, but whatever (for now)
      // I also tested of course without having to do that.
   ```
3. in my method that uses newFinalArray, the method is a recursive function that calls itself. each time it calls, it should add the dictionary object to the array (or does it?)

   ```
   -(void)digTree:(NSArray *)array{  

        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array){
          // looping through the array
          [self newFinalArray addObject:[dictionary]];
         // more other code, and somewhere along the way I recurse
           [self digTree:anotherArray];
         }
    }
   ```
4. when I try to NSLog (@"my final array is %@", newFinalArray)  I get (null).

I am probably missing something here. I tried to add "nil" at the end. I am a little new/green to this , so if someone can lend a hand and let me know how to populate my newFinalArray with these dictionary objects it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Just a tip: Never "yeah, whatever" a warning, especially if you're having a problem in that vicinity. Odds are good that (as in this case) it's pointing right in the direction of your mistake. A lot of pros use the compiler flag to treat warnings as hard errors so they *can't* ignore them.

Comment: (I never do, its just that I did not believe the warning was relevant to my question), but thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: Ya, well it's very relevant :) The code could not possibly work with that line as it is!

Comment: First fix all warnings, then ask questions.

Answer (score 9):

`[[newFinalArray alloc] init];`

should be:

`newFinalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

This line is wrong too:

`[self newFinalArray addObject:[dictionary]];`

it should be:

`[newFinalArray addObject:dictionary];`

Comment: hi thanks for your response @brainfeeder. quick question though what is wrong with the "self" reference if newFinalArray is a member of this class?

Comment: @djeddiej The syntax is not right. It should be either `[self newFinalArray]` or `self.newFinalArray` (dot-notation syntax). Be aware that by using `self` you're actually invoking a property (it's not the same as `this` in C++, for example).

Answer (score 5):

The first thing I notice that is wrong, is it should be:

```
newFinalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

in viewDidLoad. See if that fixes it. It looks like there are other things wrong as well, so turn on warnings and see what else the compiler warns you about for hints.

How are the dictionaries stored? An alternative/probably easier way to do this would probably be to use arrayWithObjects:. Also, when using addObject:, there is no need to add nil (in fact, you *can't* add nil).

Comment: thanks for the rapid response. I just tried it and that did not return anything...I'll edit the question a little more.